# My title isn't in the center

Tags: html, css, center

I am completely positive that my code causes my title to be in the center of my textbox, however, it doesn't look like it is! Can someone check that my code is sound?

```css
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.home-about-textbox {
  background-color: #232323;
  padding: 4em;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -2.65%;
  outline: 2px solid #00ff6c;
  outline-offset: -2.5em;
  color: #FFF;
}

.home-about-textbox h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00ff6c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="home-about">
    <div class="home-about-textbox">
      <h1>Who I am</h1>
      <p>I'm a young website developer who focusses on primarily making websites that are proven to have a <strong>high conversion rate</strong> so that my clients can experience that feeling of <strong>ever increasing cash flow!</strong></p>
      <p>I usually like to spend a lot of my freetime working on either: a client's website design, or my personal website design. I am never the 'second-best' when it comes to website design which is why I offer numerous <strong>free</strong> design revisions
        upon submission!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Image of the Textbox:
[image: The Black/Green Text is the box I am referring to!]

Comment: remove all the `width:...`

Comment: In the container and in the .home-about-textbox?

Comment: yes try and see .. you may also remove the negative margin left

Comment: `margin-left: -2.65%;` seems suspect.. whats the purpose?

Comment: container is 95% but inside element width 100vh and margin-left: - 2.65%, I think this is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `width: 100vw`from `.home-about-textbox` seems fixed problem, no?

```css
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.home-about-textbox {
  background-color: #232323;
  padding: 4em;
 
  margin-left: -2.65%;
  outline: 2px solid #00ff6c;
  outline-offset: -2.5em;
  color: #FFF;
}

.home-about-textbox h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00ff6c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="home-about">
    <div class="home-about-textbox">
      <h1>Who I am</h1>
      <p>I'm a young website developer who focusses on primarily making websites that are proven to have a <strong>high conversion rate</strong> so that my clients can experience that feeling of <strong>ever increasing cash flow!</strong></p>
      <p>I usually like to spend a lot of my freetime working on either: a client's website design, or my personal website design. I am never the 'second-best' when it comes to website design which is why I offer numerous <strong>free</strong> design revisions
        upon submission!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write the `<p>` or `<div>` inside a `<center>` tag. It causes anything to be centered. In order to avoid further problems isolote the element to be centered from other elements.